# How to show $L(R,R;R)\cong R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

$$
L(R,R;R)=\{f:R\times R\rightarrow R  : f \text{ is bilinear } \}
$$
Adding the addition and scalar product, $L(R,R;R)$ is a vector space .

How to show $L(R,R;R)\cong R$ ? Besides what is the basis of $L(R,R;R)$ ?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: let $f\colon R\times R\to R$ be a bilinear map. Then, for $(x,y)\in R\times R$ you have
$$
f(x,y)=xyf(1,1)
$$